# Thinkpad X1 Carbon: Headphones not working

Tags: sound, 20.04, thinkpad

I am using a 6th gen Thinkpad X1 Carbon with Ubuntu 20.04. No matter which headphones I plug in, the sound is not working for all of them. They are recognized correctly in the audio settings menu als headphones, but they don't play any sound.

The laptop speakers work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in a terminal:
`sudo alsactl restore`
If problem persists, try to manually change audio parameters in 2 ways:

- Install  pavucontrol "pulseaudio volume control" with command `sudo apt install pavucontrol`
  Run  pavucontrol (via command or menu) :
  in **output device tab**, test manual change  port to "headphone" or "speaker"  (also in  **configuration** tab, check  "profile" is  set  analog)
- next control is alsamixer (with headphones connected):

  - Run `alsamixer`  (or `alsamixer -c1` if hdmi audio is first) in  a terminal (maximize window)
  - using left/right arrow keys to scroll thru faders, **raise  volumes**  master/speaker/headphones (up/down arrow key) , **unmute** muted faders with <kbd>m</kbd> key  (muted fader have a MM label) .
  - desactivate and activate "automute" control which could be screwed . Check also switching on/off "independant HP" and "loopback" . Normally this 2 last parameters are disabled. On some pc, i have seen  one of these 3 functions  create problem .
- if no success, it may be a driver problem , whats the result of
  `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* |grep Cod`
- Just saw a  similar recent  bug  reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-ucm-conf/+bug/1872108)  , low headphone volume on Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 7th g